# Issue finding CSS selectors with different values

Tags: java, selenium, user-interface, testing, automated-tests

I am having issue with selectors that have different values associated with them, currently i have 4 elements:

```
data-qa-pick-title="0"
data-qa-pick-title="1"
data-qa-pick-title="2"
data-qa-pick-title="3"
```

But currently, I am getting the warning:

> org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: invalid selector: An
>   invalid or illegal selector was specified

when I use `data-qa-pick-title="0"`, etc.

I'm guessing this is because of the ="0" part but I can't seem to figure out what attributes to use here?

HTML:

```
<article class="_ua2rle">
   <article class="_p518npy">
      <div class="_1woz4hd">
         <div>
            <h1 data-qa-game-name="" class="_1dg3j5db">Multi Day Game</h1>
            <h2 class="_1ah1pl68">9/18 - 9/21</h2>
            <section aria-label="game_prize" class="_1eiqo0c">
               <p aria-label="game_prize_prefix" class="_nuf05ac" data-qa-prize-label="">Prize:</p>
               <h1 data-qa-prize-value="" aria-label="game_prize_description" class="_1usxso2m">€10</h1>
            </section>
         </div>
         <div class="_aryvye">
            <div class="_1rzj9z6">
               <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" width="16px" height="17px" class="_1tdu91v4">
                  <title>Number of players</title>
                  <g>
                     <g>
                        <circle cx="50" cy="24.8" r="24.6"></circle>
                        <path d="M99.2,87.8c0,4.4,0,12.2,0,12.2H0.8c0,0,0-7.7,0-12.2c0-13.6,22-24.6,49.2-24.6
                           S99.2,74.2,99.2,87.8z"></path>
                     </g>
                  </g>
               </svg>
               <span class="_1nrqntf5" data-qa-num-players-value="">1</span>
            </div>
            <div class="_1iw4ka9">
               <p class="_13z1sq2">–</p>
               <div class="_1s8d7xt">
                  <div data-qa-pick-state="0">
                     <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32" class="_1x3k1as">
                        <title>Pick</title>
                        <circle class="_1t4d67p" r="16" cx="16" cy="16" stroke="#DDDDDD" stroke-dasharray="0 100"></circle>
                        <circle class="_1f2xgws" stroke="#DDDDDD" r="16" cx="16" cy="16"></circle>
                     </svg>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="_1s8d7xt">
                  <div data-qa-pick-state="0">
                     <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32" class="_1x3k1as">
                        <title>Pick</title>
                        <circle class="_1t4d67p" r="16" cx="16" cy="16" stroke="#DDDDDD" stroke-dasharray="0 100"></circle>
                        <circle class="_1f2xgws" stroke="#DDDDDD" r="16" cx="16" cy="16"></circle>
                     </svg>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="_1s8d7xt">
                  <div data-qa-pick-state="0">
                     <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32" class="_1x3k1as">
                        <title>Pick</title>
                        <circle class="_1t4d67p" r="16" cx="16" cy="16" stroke="#DDDDDD" stroke-dasharray="0 100"></circle>
                        <circle class="_1f2xgws" stroke="#DDDDDD" r="16" cx="16" cy="16"></circle>
                     </svg>
                  </div>
               </div>
               <div class="_1s8d7xt">
                  <div data-qa-pick-state="0">
                     <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32" class="_1x3k1as">
                        <title>Pick</title>
                        <circle class="_1t4d67p" r="16" cx="16" cy="16" stroke="#DDDDDD" stroke-dasharray="0 100"></circle>
                        <circle class="_1f2xgws" stroke="#DDDDDD" r="16" cx="16" cy="16"></circle>
                     </svg>
                  </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="_1cex955">
         <div class="_z0cnykj"></div>
      </div>
   </article>
   <div class="_by9jvv">
      <section class="_19gaaoo">
         <div>
            <p data-qa-pick-title="0" class="_3cal6hx">Pick:</p>
            <p data-qa-market-title="0" class="_3cal6hx">Market:</p>
            <p data-qa-fixture-title="0" class="_3cal6hx">Fixture:</p>
            <p data-qa-date-title="0" class="_3cal6hx">Date:</p>
            <p data-qa-points-title="0" class="_myfp0gx">Points:</p>
         </div>
         <div class="_bc4egv">
            <p data-qa-pick-value="0" class="_5953se3">Draw</p>
            <p data-qa-market-value="0" class="_5953se3">Full Time Result</p>
            <p data-qa-fixture-value="0" class="_5953se3">Leeds United vs Preston North End</p>
            <p data-qa-date-value="0" class="_5953se3">Sep 18, 7:45 PM</p>
            <p data-qa-points-value="0" class="_1lauivqf">350</p>
         </div>
         <div class="_1rzj9z6">
            <div class="_nv9fvh">
               <div data-qa-pick-state="0">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32" class="_1x3k1as">
                     <title>Pick</title>
                     <circle class="_1t4d67p" r="16" cx="16" cy="16" stroke="#DDDDDD" stroke-dasharray="0 100"></circle>
                     <circle class="_1f2xgws" stroke="#DDDDDD" r="16" cx="16" cy="16"></circle>
                  </svg>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </section>
      <section class="_19gaaoo">
         <div>
            <p data-qa-pick-title="1" class="_3cal6hx">Pick:</p>
            <p data-qa-market-title="1" class="_3cal6hx">Market:</p>
            <p data-qa-fixture-title="1" class="_3cal6hx">Fixture:</p>
            <p data-qa-date-title="1" class="_3cal6hx">Date:</p>
            <p data-qa-points-title="1" class="_myfp0gx">Points:</p>
         </div>
         <div class="_bc4egv">
            <p data-qa-pick-value="1" class="_5953se3">Wigan Athletic</p>
            <p data-qa-market-value="1" class="_5953se3">Full Time Result</p>
            <p data-qa-fixture-value="1" class="_5953se3">Wigan Athletic vs Hull City</p>
            <p data-qa-date-value="1" class="_5953se3">Sep 18, 7:45 PM</p>
            <p data-qa-points-value="1" class="_1lauivqf">195</p>
         </div>
         <div class="_1rzj9z6">
            <div class="_nv9fvh">
               <div data-qa-pick-state="0">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32" class="_1x3k1as">
                     <title>Pick</title>
                     <circle class="_1t4d67p" r="16" cx="16" cy="16" stroke="#DDDDDD" stroke-dasharray="0 100"></circle>
                     <circle class="_1f2xgws" stroke="#DDDDDD" r="16" cx="16" cy="16"></circle>
                  </svg>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </section>
      <section class="_19gaaoo">
         <div>
            <p data-qa-pick-title="2" class="_3cal6hx">Pick:</p>
            <p data-qa-market-title="2" class="_3cal6hx">Market:</p>
            <p data-qa-fixture-title="2" class="_3cal6hx">Fixture:</p>
            <p data-qa-date-title="2" class="_3cal6hx">Date:</p>
            <p data-qa-points-title="2" class="_myfp0gx">Points:</p>
         </div>
         <div class="_bc4egv">
            <p data-qa-pick-value="2" class="_5953se3">Draw</p>
            <p data-qa-market-value="2" class="_5953se3">Full Time Result</p>
            <p data-qa-fixture-value="2" class="_5953se3">Aston Villa vs Rotherham United</p>
            <p data-qa-date-value="2" class="_5953se3">Sep 18, 7:45 PM</p>
            <p data-qa-points-value="2" class="_1lauivqf">433</p>
         </div>
         <div class="_1rzj9z6">
            <div class="_nv9fvh">
               <div data-qa-pick-state="0">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32" class="_1x3k1as">
                     <title>Pick</title>
                     <circle class="_1t4d67p" r="16" cx="16" cy="16" stroke="#DDDDDD" stroke-dasharray="0 100"></circle>
                     <circle class="_1f2xgws" stroke="#DDDDDD" r="16" cx="16" cy="16"></circle>
                  </svg>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </section>
      <section class="_19gaaoo">
         <div>
            <p data-qa-pick-title="3" class="_3cal6hx">Pick:</p>
            <p data-qa-market-title="3" class="_3cal6hx">Market:</p>
            <p data-qa-fixture-title="3" class="_3cal6hx">Fixture:</p>
            <p data-qa-date-title="3" class="_3cal6hx">Date:</p>
            <p data-qa-points-title="3" class="_myfp0gx">Points:</p>
         </div>
         <div class="_bc4egv">
            <p data-qa-pick-value="3" class="_5953se3">Draw</p>
            <p data-qa-market-value="3" class="_5953se3">Full Time Result</p>
            <p data-qa-fixture-value="3" class="_5953se3">Ipswich Town vs Brentford</p>
            <p data-qa-date-value="3" class="_5953se3">Sep 18, 7:45 PM</p>
            <p data-qa-points-value="3" class="_1lauivqf">360</p>
         </div>
         <div class="_1rzj9z6">
            <div class="_nv9fvh">
               <div data-qa-pick-state="0">
                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 32 32" class="_1x3k1as">
                     <title>Pick</title>
                     <circle class="_1t4d67p" r="16" cx="16" cy="16" stroke="#DDDDDD" stroke-dasharray="0 100"></circle>
                     <circle class="_1f2xgws" stroke="#DDDDDD" r="16" cx="16" cy="16"></circle>
                  </svg>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </section>
      <section class="_rci9mp">
         <div class="_jro6t0">
            <div>
               <p class="_12nchi6">Entry Fee:</p>
               <p class="_12nchi6">Date Placed:</p>
               <p class="_12nchi6">Unique ID:</p>
            </div>
            <div>
               <p class="_nqzawj">Free To Play</p>
               <p class="_nqzawj">Sep 17, 3:30 PM</p>
               <p class="_xswzd0s">17u9wadfk1c_efcb68b5-446a-430f-8c97-56027658682b</p>
            </div>
         </div>
      </section>
   </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Show the HTML code and your css selector you tried.

Comment: I see no selectors here.

Comment: `tagname:nth-child(index)`   replace `tagname` and `index` with real values and let me know

Comment: Added the HTML there

Comment: which element you want ?

Comment: data-qa-pick-title="0" and data-qa-pick-title="1", how do i separate them?? using the numbers?

Comment: Do you want to get all the title like `data-qa-pick-title="0"` `data-qa-pick-title="1"` and so on ?

Comment: Yep thats exactly it

Comment: @FearghalQA, updated the answer let me know

Comment: @FearghalQA, how is going? Did you try my answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below cssSelector :

```
List<WebElement> all = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("p._3cal6hx:nth-child(1)"));
```

And loop through all the element to use further

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to select the element with a drop down? 
Can you show the HTML part of the element where you want to select and the code you used?

If it's a drop down,

```
Select title= new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("yourID")));
    title.selectByIndex(0);
```

This might work.

Comment: No its not a drop down, its basically four "picks" and each pick has the selector data-qa-pick-title=0,1,2,3. im just trying to seperate them as data-qa-pick-title=0 is invalid

Comment: it might work with xpaths or css selectors then, 
try x paths like 
for Pick 0  >>  //section/div/p
for Pick 1  >>  //section[2]/div/p .. etc

Comment: Problem is the code is always changing for xpaths, so these selectors are the only constant

Comment: Oh, In that case is it possible to assign a id in your code and refer it in the test script ? when the elements are dynamic normally it's the best solution. ( if the 4 pick paragraph elements remains unchanged )

Comment: They are the "ids" that have been added

Comment: 'data-qa-pick-title' If I'm not wrong it's a custom tag right ? I might be wrong but I think that's the problem. I think Selenium is unable to understand custom tags like that. Insted of 'data-qa-pick-title= 0' if you can use something like id = "data-qa-pick-title_0" and use the locator as By.id("data-qa-pick-title_0") this should probably work :)